# X86 assembly mul error masm

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

A simple question , why doesn't this work:

```
    mov ebx,m[edx*4]
    mov eax,conv[edx*4]
    mul ebx
```

I checked `m[edx*4]` it has 2 (what should be there) same for `conv[edx*4]`.

It's basically just a `2*3`.

`m` and `conv` are `dd 2500 dup(?)`    <---- Thats why It doesn't work ?

Comment: You are aware that _EDX_ will be overwritten by this multiplication instruction `mul ebx`?

Comment: @Michael Petch ,umm no ,why?EDIT.. wait even if EDX isnt used to store the result , it is still overwritten ?

Comment: See the `mul` instruction: http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_210.html  32 bit unsigned  integer * 32 bit unsigned integer will be placed into the 64-bit value across the _EDX_ and _EAX_ registers. _EDX_ will have the upper 32 bits of the result, and _EAX_ will have the lower 32-bits of the result.

Comment: Ok then how to get my result,how to combine EDX and EAX?Wait nevermind that how to store a 64-bit....

Comment: Is there a way to convert the result(64-bit) to 32-bit .I want to put the answer in a matrix..

Comment: If you just want the lower 32-bits, just use _EAX_. You can just throw away what is in _EDX_, but since you are using _EDX_ as part of the memory operands you are going to have to save _EDX_ before the `mul` and restore it after, or use a different register for memory addressing.

Comment: @Michael Petch Thanks you very much ,the EDX was the problem ,I just had to save the value . :D

Comment: It makes much more sense to use EBX (instead of EDX) as array index, and EDX (instead of EBX) to hold the right operand. Because it is no problem to have the latter being overwritten by MUL. Choose your registers wisely.

Comment: If you need a 32 bit multiply use the two operand `IMUL r32, r/m32` instruction.

Comment: I see ,from now on I wont use EDX as an index anymore.I will use IMUL as well, thanks guys ^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to follow:
Check what the 32 bit value is at memory location m and conv
What is the value of edx when you start mov ebx,m[edx*4]
Check if the expected values in ebx and eax are correct
Edx will be overridden because MUL and IMUL instructions stores the result in EDX and EAX 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings

MUL is used for unsigned multiplications, IMUL for signed multiplications.  This means that, in contrary what Jester says: for 32 bits operands you use MUL (unsigned), for 31 bits with sign in 32th bit you use IMUL.

If this all is ok, you should have in edx = 0 and eax = 6 if m[edx*4] = 2 and conv[edx*4] = 3 (or vice versa)
mind that conv and m are 32 bits, with the least significant byte in the lowest memory location.

correct me if I'm wrong.